# Calling stored procedure using JPA @Query()

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to execute SQL Server stored procedure using JPA @Query() like given below

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "exec [dbo].[uspGetVinorUserInfo] =:vin")
List<Object> findCommandStatusByVinOrderByCreatedTimestampDesc(@Param("vin") String vin);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to find a way to use @Query to execute MS-SQL SP, but I used the below code to execute the MS-SQL Stored Procedure and it is working fine.

```
package com.ford.cevs.scheduler.repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.ParameterMode;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery;

@Repository
public class CommandStatusRepositoryImpl implements CommandStatusRepository {

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;

@Override
public String executeCommandStatusPurge(Integer minutes) {

        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("MyProcedureName");

        // set parameters
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("minutes", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedure.setParameter("minutes", minutes);
        storedProcedure.execute();

        String result = (String)storedProcedure.getSingleResult();

        return result;
}
}
```

MS-SQL Store Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedureName] @minutes int 
AS 
   SET nocount ON

    DECLARE @Message VARCHAR(40); 

      SET @Message = ' Completed, ' 

      -- <Your code> --- @minutes 

        SELECT @Message
```

The below link shows different ways:
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery

Answer (score 0):

It is possible since JPA 2.1 version, please read about [NamedStoredProcedureQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQuery.html) anotation. But it seems to me that you use some specific JPA implementation or some framework (possibly [Spring Data JPA](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/)?), because `@Query` annotation is not a part of [JPA specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/package-summary.html); so it's difficult to me to provide concrete code snippet for your case.

Comment: Do you have any sample full code for calling MS SQL Storedprocedure using NamedStoredProcedureQuery